# Rails 4 refresh/autoload list of translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Our project has translation files that exist in specific branches. Often when switching between branches, I receive the following error:

```
I18n::InvalidLocaleData
can not load translations from /.../config/locales/feature.yml: #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /.../config/locales/feature.yml>
```

I can fix this by restarting the server, but I was wondering if there is a way to (in development) have rails watch the locales folder to check for added/removed files.

Comment: I think you can't, look at this issue on I18n https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/issues/301

Comment: why can't you merge the changes from branches every now and then?